# How to find a point of an elliptic curve in crypto++ (with given x)? Or how to compute a root in finite field? Or root of Polynomial Ring?

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++, elliptic-curve

Is there any way in crypto++ to check if an EC contains a point with a given x-coordinate?

One solution would be solving the EC polynomial for given x. One side of the equation already done in code. I 'just' need to compute the root of it (over a finite field)

```
//clang++ -o ectest ectest.cpp -lcryptopp
#include "cryptopp/eccrypto.h"
#include "cryptopp/oids.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using namespace CryptoPP;
    typedef DL_GroupParameters_EC<ECP> GroupParameters;
    typedef DL_GroupParameters_EC<ECP>::Element Element;
    
    GroupParameters group;
    group.Initialize(ASN1::secp256k1());
        
    //I want to check if the EC has a point with x-cooridnate x=13
    Integer x = 13;
    
    Integer ecmod = group.GetCurve().GetField().GetModulus();
    ModularArithmetic ma = ModularArithmetic(ecmod);

    //the following equation need to be solved:
    //y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B \mod ecmod
    Integer x3 = ma.Multiply(x,x);
    x3 = ma.Multiply(x3,x);
    Integer xa = ma.Multiply(group.GetCurve().GetA(),x);
    Integer xb = group.GetCurve().GetB();
    Integer sr = ma.Add(x3,xa);
    sr = ma.Add(sr,xb);

    //y^2 = sr
    //how to compute the root out of sr?
    //or is there any other way to check if the EC contains a point with x?
}
```

Comment: for i from 0 to ecmod-1, if `i*i==sr`, then y is i?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont problem is that's about 2^255 (approx 10^76) numbers. Some solving formulas exist but it can get complicated in some cases.

Comment: For the other question that you deleted in crypto, make sure that the point representations are the same. crypto++ Can use [Montgomery Representation](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/4e56a6393dced07071dd1a73e027e3679eafb1ca/ecp.cpp#L492)

Comment: @kelalaka I got the same result as in sage math by using CascadeMultiply(1,p,1,G) instead of Add(p,G). Finding y for given x only serve as initialization. The main operations are CascadeMultiply with different power of generators multiple times in row. So it should be faster if I convert it to MR.

Comment: Honestly, I need to check the details of the implementation. Mongomery normally only provides x-coordinate, and that is enough in ECDH. Resolving the y coordinate is not an easy issue. I remember a paper about that. I'll look at that. Inform you later.

Comment: @kelalaka thanks but no need for me right now. I'll pause EC investigation for now. I think I got another solution for my problem without EC. However if you are interested by yourself I would be happy to get informed by the result (for my future work with EC). And determining y is quite compute intensive for primes mod 4=1 (cprd to 3). There you need some special algorithm like [Tonelli-Shanks_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm). Implementation might be complicated but its quite efficient. If it is mod a non-prime there exist no efficient algorithm afaik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. The library has support for compression and decompression of points. During the decompression, the library must find `y` if it can.

The header of the [DecodePoint](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/4e56a6393dced07071dd1a73e027e3679eafb1ca/ecp.cpp#L119)

```
bool ECP::DecodePoint(ECP::Point &P, BufferedTransformation &bt, size_t encodedPointLen) const
```

The error returned with

```
if (Jacobi(P.y, p) !=1)
    return false;
```

You can construct your point as compressed, or better use this part from DecodePoint; just add the below lines into your code;

```
//include these
#include "cryptopp/nbtheory.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace CryptoPP;

Integer getSquareRoot( Integer &y, Integer &mod) {

   if (Jacobi(y, mod) !=1)
        return -1;

    return y  = ModularSquareRoot(y, mod);
     
}

    // In the main
    //After sr = ma.Add(sr,xb);

    Integer y  = getSquareRoot(sr, ecmod);
    if ( y != -1 ) {
        std::cout << IntToString<Integer>(y) << std::endl;
    } else {         
        std::cout << IntToString<Integer>(sr);
        std::cout << " has not square root to " << ecmod << std::endl;
    }
```

outputs

`20267456347483554069520440766283645831919514026818877192810320909941447705364`

---

**Note**: if you print with

```
std::cout << y << std::endl;
```

There will be a dot in the end. The library [warns about this](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/4e56a6393dced07071dd1a73e027e3679eafb1ca/integer.h#L708).

```
/// The output includes the suffix \a h (for hex), \a . (\a dot, for dec)
/// and \a o (for octal). There is currently no way to suppress the suffix.
/// \details If you want to print an Integer without the suffix or using an arbitrary base, then
///   use IntToString<Integer>().
```

Comment: thank you. I almost implemented it for myself. Already did the 'mod 4=3' case. www.cryptopp.com should have some search on it. Also google has no result with 'site:cryptopp.com root'

Comment: I did search over the code on GitHub. I looked for compression ( the second sentence) since it is so common and preferred since provides some point validation. During that, I've also looked at your deleted question, too. I hope that is clear, too.

Answer (score 1):

Although you already have valid and simple [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66622936/941531), I still decided to implement my own solution from scratch in pure C++, because your task is very interesting.

My quite large solution doesn't use Crypto++, but tries to implement all algorithms from scratch in C++. It is intended only for curiosity and scientific and educational purpose. It is not intended to be as fast and as simple as pure Crypto++ solution.

It is known that if modulus is any prime of any form, then square root can be found through well known and very fast algorithm of [Tonelli Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm). It is main part of code that follows below.

Also if modulus is a prime of form `p % 4 == 3` then its root also can be found easily by formula `root = n^((p + 1) / 4) % p`. Which is much shorter than Shanks Tonelli algorithm, but Shanks Tonelli works for all cases, even when `p % 4 != 3`.

Besides mentioned above algorithms I also used [Modular Exponentation by Squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) and [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion).

Params of curve Secp256k1 were taken from [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1) and [here](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf):

```
p      = 0xFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE FFFFFC2F
a      = 0
b      = 7
base_x = 0x79BE667E F9DCBBAC 55A06295 CE870B07 029BFCDB 2DCE28D9 59F2815B 16F81798
base_y = 0x483ADA77 26A3C465 5DA4FBFC 0E1108A8 FD17B448 A6855419 9C47D08F FB10D4B8
q      = 0xFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE BAAEDCE6 AF48A03B BFD25E8C D0364141
```

My code can be run straight away after compilation and it shows all timings and results on console, see example output after code below. For test purpose I iterate all X in range [0..50] and show which of them give valid root for Y. As it is known around 50% values of X will give correct solution.

To compile my program besides standard C++ library I use only [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) library for arbitrary integer arithmetics. It can be installed in Linux through `sudo apt install libgmp-dev`. And in Windows after install [VCPKG](https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html) package manager you can do `vcpkg install gmp`, plus Windows will need to provide manually vckpg include path and libraries for linking. I tested compilation and work of program in CLang and MSVC.

Also click `Try it online!` link below to test run of program online on GodBolt servers.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/jqhGdfhK4)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>

#include <gmpxx.h>

#define ASSERT_MSG(cond, msg) { if (!(cond)) throw std::runtime_error("Assertion (" #cond ") failed at line " + std::to_string(__LINE__) + "! Msg: '" + std::string(msg) + "'."); }
#define ASSERT(cond) ASSERT_MSG(cond, "")
#define COUT(code) { std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> lock(cout_mux); std::cout code; std::cout << std::flush; }
#define LN { COUT(<< "LN " << __LINE__ << std::endl); }
#define JOIN0(x, y) x##y
#define JOIN(x, y) JOIN0(x, y)
#define TEST(name) static void JOIN(Test_##name, __LINE__)(); static bool const JOIN(reg_test_##name, __LINE__) = []{ g_tests.push_back(std::make_pair(#name, &JOIN(Test_##name, __LINE__))); return true; }(); static void JOIN(Test_##name, __LINE__)()
#define RUN_TESTS() { for (auto & [name, f]: g_tests) { std::cout << "Test " << name << " " << std::flush; auto tb = Time(); f(); tb = Time() - tb; std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << tb << " sec" << std::endl; } }

using u8  = uint8_t;
using u16 = uint16_t;
using i16 = int16_t;
using u32 = uint32_t;
using i32 = int32_t;
using u64 = uint64_t;
using i64 = int64_t;

static std::recursive_mutex cout_mux;
static std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::function<void()>>> g_tests;

template <typename T> struct DWordOf;
template <> struct DWordOf<mpz_class> { using type = mpz_class; };

template <typename T>
u32 ToU32(T const & N) { return mpz_class(N).get_ui(); }

double Time() {
    static auto const gtb = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - gtb).count();
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> Uniquize(std::vector<T> vec) {
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());
    return std::move(vec);
}

template <typename T, typename DT = typename DWordOf<T>::type>
DT DTMul(T const & a, T const & b) {
    return DT(a) * b;
}

template <typename T>
T PowMod(T a, T b, T const & c)  {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method
    using DT = typename DWordOf<T>::type;
    T r = 1;
    while (b != 0) {
        if (ToU32<T>(b) & 1)
            r = T(DTMul(r, a) % c);
        a = T(DTMul(a, a) % c);
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return r;
}

template <typename T>
int EulerCriterion(T const & n, T const & p) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    auto const val = PowMod<T>(n, (p - 1) >> 1, p);
    ASSERT_MSG(val == 1 || val == p - 1, "val " + IntToStr(val) + " p " + IntToStr(p));
    return val == 1 ? 1 : -1;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> SquareRoot_Mod4_3(T n, T const & p) {
    using DT = typename DWordOf<T>::type;
    ASSERT(p % 4 == 3);
    n %= p;
    T const r = PowMod<T>(n, (p + 1) >> 2, p);
    if (DTMul(r, r) % p == n % p)
        return Uniquize<T>(std::vector<T>({r, p - r}));
    return {};
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> SquareRoot_TonelliShanks(T n, T p) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm
    // see also https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1407.pdf
    using DT = typename DWordOf<T>::type;
    n %= p;
    if (n == 0)
        return {0};
    if (p == 2)
        return {n};
    {
        auto const ec = EulerCriterion<T>(n, p);
        ASSERT(ec == 1 || ec == -1);
        if (ec == -1)
            return {};
    }
    if (p % 4 == 3) {
        return SquareRoot_Mod4_3<T>(n, p);
    }
    T Q = p - 1, S = 0;
    while ((Q & 1) == 0) {
        Q >>= 1;
        ++S;
    }
    T z = 0;
    for (z = 2; z < p; ++z) {
        if (EulerCriterion<T>(z, p) == -1)
            break;
    }
    ASSERT_MSG(z < p, "n " + IntToStr(n) + ", p " + IntToStr(p));
    T M = S, c = PowMod<T>(z, Q, p), t = PowMod<T>(n, Q, p), R = PowMod<T>(n, (Q + 1) / 2, p), r = 0;
    ASSERT(M < u32(-1));
    while (true) {
        if (t == 0) {
            r = 0;
            break;
        }
        if (t == 1) {
            r = R;
            break;
        }
        T sqt = t;
        u32 i = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < M; ++i) {
            sqt = T(DTMul<T>(sqt, sqt) % p);
            if (sqt == 1)
                break;
        }
        ASSERT(i < M);
        //ASSERT(M - i - 1 < BiSize(T));
        T b = PowMod<T>(c, T(1) << ToU32(M - i - 1), p);
        M = i;
        c = T(DTMul<T>(b, b) % p);
        t = T(DTMul<T>(t, c) % p);
        R = T(DTMul<T>(R, b) % p);
    }
    ASSERT(DTMul<T>(r, r) % p == n);
    return Uniquize<T>(std::vector<T>({r, p - r}));
}

mpz_class MpzFromStr(std::string const & s, size_t base = 0) {
    mpz_class r;
    mpz_set_str(r.get_mpz_t(), s.c_str(), int(base));
    return r;
}

std::string MpzToStr(mpz_class n, size_t base = 10) {
    std::string s(mpz_sizeinbase(n.get_mpz_t(), base) + 5, '\x00');
    mpz_get_str(s.data(), base, n.get_mpz_t());
    return s.c_str();
}

template <typename T>
std::string IntToStr(T const & n) { return MpzToStr(n); }

TEST(Main) {
    COUT(<< std::endl);
    // https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1
    // https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf
    // secp256k1 params
    mpz_class const
        p  = MpzFromStr("0xFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE FFFFFC2F"),
        a  = 0,
        b  = 7,
        bx = MpzFromStr("0x79BE667E F9DCBBAC 55A06295 CE870B07 029BFCDB 2DCE28D9 59F2815B 16F81798"),
        by = MpzFromStr("0x483ADA77 26A3C465 5DA4FBFC 0E1108A8 FD17B448 A6855419 9C47D08F FB10D4B8"),
        q  = MpzFromStr("0xFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE BAAEDCE6 AF48A03B BFD25E8C D0364141");
    auto EllipticCurve = [&](auto const & x) {
        return mpz_class((x * x * x + a * x + b) % p);
    };
    auto const p_len = IntToStr(p).size();
    for (u32 ix = 0; ix <= 50; ++ix) {
        mpz_class const x = ix, ec_value = EllipticCurve(x);
        auto roots = SquareRoot_TonelliShanks<mpz_class>(ec_value, p);
        if (roots.empty())
            continue;
        ASSERT(DTMul(roots.at(0), roots.at(0)) % p == ec_value);
        COUT(<< "x = " << std::setw(3) << ix << ", y = " << std::setw(p_len) << IntToStr(roots.at(0)) << std::endl);
    }
}

int main() {
    try {
        RUN_TESTS();
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        COUT(<< "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Test Main 
x =   1, y =  29896722852569046015560700294576055776214335159245303116488692907525646231534
x =   2, y =  46580984542418694471253469931035885126779956971428003686700937153791839982430
x =   3, y =  21320899557911560362763253855565071047772010424612278905734793689199612115787
x =   4, y =  40508090799132825824753983223610497876805216745196355809233758402754120847507
x =   6, y =  19112057249303445409876026535760519114630369653212530612662492210011362204224
x =   8, y =  24055953608229461237864090884685780858714989825500507741703654067262135535697
x =  12, y =  31068864722486242021761838950999795945745157936084027215252040495978276421796
x =  13, y =  20267456347483554069520440766283645831919514026818877192810320909941447705364
x =  14, y =  44647516152956573151520437476900496747965187933683819148138195218441524686495
x =  16, y =   6086653149631013477190265492692874244435390487330439650246572165529255539543
x =  20, y =  20676141886993640210986884816394413846392747094661403271705441051670760124834
x =  22, y =  17384355509374335117451332188362459136087449825697451396219196747631138909398
x =  25, y =   1102551495006820024539592786237854453433258304779672753607085440481650452602
x =  27, y =  12150456207077715994570159310959166905435600970349836880310459338926638464144
x =  32, y =  25427332243426016000490343799988059539558736656305693852522166340470154069724
x =  33, y =  51173090447386785350599579912891887007487842540657484998530120736905211706882
x =  38, y =   9646363146228555846652555429881922614278153944052502987030828554623605767881
x =  39, y =  28197313212501135724540236089620685652765900040943429810123028520443371359923
x =  43, y =  56572214809736663028893280596571268084211571988499307500846727553699476699834
x =  44, y =  29878230023088480380896492456768186169213097553238389007631075402030495033678
x =  45, y =   9813211421898343856404272161982377846064062305226732735279529255438243343429
x =  47, y =  37644263369555793562992696144870056406951060257194647817532744844486199964398
x =  48, y =  22158093920271983590355401047321466603843412217042649359409719523363101162922
0.064 sec
```

Comment: wow! some nice work.And also a informative description. I would like to give some extra points but I can not mark it as the answer (not crypto++ related).

Comment: @J.Doe Thanks! UpVoting is quite enough. Of course I certainly knew that you can't Accept my answer only because it is not Cypto++ solution as you requested in your question. I did this anwer only for educational purpose, for those people who want to know how all this stuff works internally. Definitely Cryptop++ solution is much shorter+simpler, also it Could be faster, but actually interesting would be to compare speed of both of them. Your prime modulus is of form `p % 4 == 3`, it means root is simply equal `root = n^((p + 1) / 4) % p`, which is blazingly fast in my code, I hope Crypto++ too

Comment: did some test: `x` up to `1e5` in your solution took 15sec. In crypto++ it took 20sec to compute `1e6`. So TonelliShanks seems to be a little slower. Only some of my results are equal to yours. E.g. for `x=2` I got `69211104694897500952317515077652022726490027694212560352756646854116994689233`. Both seem to work out. Multiple solutions for `y^2 = s`